# How does one properly handle complex recursive lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have two different structs. The main one, `Example`, and one that wraps a recursively-typed function, `SFunction`.

Here is what they look like:

```
struct Example {
    text: String,
}

impl<'a> Example {
     fn function(&'a mut self) -> SFunction<'a> {
         let closed_function = move || self.do_something();
         SFunction::new(Box::new(closed_function))
     }                           

     fn do_something(&'a mut self) -> SFunction<'a> {
        SFunction::empty()
     }
}                 

struct SFunction<'a> {
    f: Option<Box<FnMut() -> SFunction<'a> + 'a>>,
}                 

impl<'a> SFunction<'a> {
    fn new(f: Box<FnMut() -> SFunction<'a> + 'a>) -> SFunction<'a> { // or no 'a on store
        SFunction { f: Some(f) }
    }   

    fn empty() -> SFunction<'a> {
        SFunction { f: None }
    }
}
```

[(Here is a version in the Rust Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b3793471d3d9da03e330&version=stable)

This does not compile, but I am confused as to why that's the case. I'm certain it has to do with the recursively typed function because the whole closure thing was compiling without that part.

Here is the error message:

```
src/main.rs:34:45: 34:59 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
src/main.rs:34          let closed_function = move || self.do_something();
                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of closure expansion
src/main.rs:34:32: 34:59 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:34:40: 34:59 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime  as defined on the block at 34:39...
src/main.rs:34          let closed_function = move || self.do_something();
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:34:40: 34:44 note: ...so that closure can access `self`
src/main.rs:34          let closed_function = move || self.do_something();
                                                      ^~~~
note: in expansion of closure expansion
src/main.rs:34:32: 34:59 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:33:49: 36:7 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 33:48...
src/main.rs:33      fn function(&'a mut self) -> SFunction<'a> {
src/main.rs:34          let closed_function = move || self.do_something();
src/main.rs:35          SFunction::new(Box::new(closed_function))
src/main.rs:36      }
src/main.rs:35:10: 35:51 note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected `SFunction<'a>`, found `SFunction<'_>`)
src/main.rs:35          SFunction::new(Box::new(closed_function))
```

Comment: In your example, please add an example use of your SFunction – I believe this will help us understand better what you intend to do.

Comment: This question has the same diagnosis, reason, and solution as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32879649/155423): use `FnOnce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that `do_something(&'a mut self)` borrows self and will not release it until it's done. But your boxed closure is "promising" to keep `do_something` callable multiple times, which is not possible (as the first call will "lock" self).

Either you can remove the dependency on self from `do_something`:

```
impl Example {
     fn function<'a>(&'a mut self) -> SFunction<'a> {
         let closed_function = move || do_something();
         SFunction::new(Box::new(closed_function))
     }                           
}                 

fn do_something<'a>() -> SFunction<'a> {
    SFunction::empty()
}
```

or you use `FnOnce` instead of `FnMut` as Shepmaster commented. Note that in this case you're moving ownership of self instead of borrowing and you promise to only ever call the closure once.

```
struct Example {
    text: String,
}

impl Example {
     fn function<'a>(self) -> SFunction<'a> {
         let closed_function = move || self.do_something();
         SFunction::new(Box::new(closed_function))
     }                           

     fn do_something<'a>(self) -> SFunction<'a> {
        SFunction::empty()
     }
}                 

struct SFunction<'a> {
    f: Option<Box<FnOnce() -> SFunction<'a> + 'a>>,
}                 

impl<'a> SFunction<'a> {
    fn new(f: Box<FnOnce() -> SFunction<'a> + 'a>) -> SFunction<'a> { // or no 'a on store
        SFunction { f: Some(f) }
    }   

    fn empty() -> SFunction<'a> {
        SFunction { f: None }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```